# iOS - Recognize UIPanGestureRecognizer just for one UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a Clear-like UITableView which contains multiple cells. Each cell has a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached and it works as expected, but I want the table view to recognize just one pan gesture recognizer, not multiple. I tried to use the `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` but it doesn't work. I think it's because it only affects multiple UIGestureRecognizers on the same view and not in multiple views.

I need some help. How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a variable in the table view to indicate whether there is an active gesture or not. Set its value according to gesture state, that is `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`. Then, ignore touches when there is already one gesture that has not ended yet.